# safari background image not showing

Tags: css, image, background, safari

got a problemi with this website: it's all ok in every browsers, except for safari. As you can see, in safari there are 2 lines of a different red color near Ferrari's, that's because safari doesn't read the background image 1x1px that I've used to keep the same red color of the image of the car (I'm using an image because the car has color profile incorporated, so the color code is different).

http://www.aformulaonehistory.com

Anyone knows why?

The structure is like this

```
<div class="background_color">
    <div id="car_in_background">
    </div>
</div>
```

with a css like this:

```
    .background_color {
        background: url('http://www.mydomain.com/img/image.jpg') repeat;
    }

    #car_in_background {
        background: url('http://www.mydomain.com/img/car.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        background-size:contain;
        height:101%;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I think that safari reads the background image, but that doesn't read the color profile. That's quite odd, because the image has ICC profile incorporated (as correctly shown in ffox and chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... if I compare the color codes in different browsers, they aren't fit together. The picture itself loaded in Safari has a complete other color than if it's on the website or than the background.

But I guess the real problem is, that the background images on safari aren't loaded at all at my browser version, so Safari uses the color fallback.

And if you are looking very detailed on your website, you can see, the grey picture doesn't fit 100% with the background as well.

You could try this:
use

```
background: #c54040;
background: url('http://www.aformulaonehistory.com/img/backgr/c54040.jpg') repeat;
```

instead of

```
background: #c54040 url('http://www.aformulaonehistory.com/img/backgr/c54040.jpg') repeat;
```

Maybe that helped ;)

Comment: yes man, that's the problem. Unfortunately the solution doesn't work.

Comment: actually, with that code I have the same problem with firefox and chrome

Comment: Did you try just to leave out the color fallback, what happens then?

Comment: tried: nothing happen. So i think that the problem is that Safari read the 1x1 px image, but without color profile. But that's weird, because the image has ICC profile incorporated, and Safari reads correctly the big image with the car, that is color profiled.

Comment: did you try to use instead of a background image via css your image with <img src="">? I guess this works, because sometimes Safari doesn't even load a background image in it's full resolution...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is according to http type images.you can try something https picture for test